# child element float on parent in 3d

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Is it possible to use css to floating 'child' on 'parent'? Like ‘other’.Now it looks like the effect is just scaling 'child' instead of translation.

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.space{
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.layer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(85.8deg) rotateY(0.1deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#parent{
  background: #fff;
}

#other{
  background: #aaa;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateZ(1050px) rotateX(72.8deg) rotateY(0.1deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class='space'>
    <div class='layer' id='parent'>
        <div id='child' style="transform: translateZ(200px);background: #555;width: 50%; height: 50%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='layer' id='other'></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on parent?

Answer (score 0):

`transform-style: preserve-3d;`
working